# Keycloak Database integration

Tags: database, spring-boot, microservices, keycloak, multi-tenant

I am using Keycloak for handling the registration of users as an IDP. The issue is I have separate tables for each type of user(based on role such as customer,vendor) with different relations for each of the tables. I am using microservice architecture for a multi-tenant application based in Spring Boot. How can I sync the keyloak users table to my role based table such that whenever a new user is added, it happens at both the places? If I use User federation can I create that sync? I would prefer if I do not have redundant data.

Comment: Yes, you can configure `Keycloak` to consult your database for all the operations. You can provide`SPI` implementation for custom logic. [Here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_user-storage-federation) is the documentation. We had a similar requirement: It syncs well.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I went through the documentation to figure our how to apply it to my use case, but I could not. I could not find any guide for linking user database hosted in postgres, or to add multitenancy support in the SPI.